# Auto return type in template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, auto

I have got multiple data classes, in various modules in my code, which i do no intend to modify whatsoever.
I have a container classes for each of them, which have a pointer to this data class, and also got a pointer to a class which is intended to hold these classes without knowing about them.

So in the container classes I implemented:

```
DataClass GetMyData (void){
   return myData;
}
```

And in the collection of these cointainer classes i created

```
template<class ContainerClass>
ContainerClass  GetContainer (void);

template<class ContainerClass>
auto    GetData (void){
    GetContainer<ContainerClass> ().GetMyData();
}
```

But whenever i try to use this GetData function i get the error

> a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined

So my question is, is it possible to use auto in this case (c++11), or i have to make my template with 2 classes?

Comment: In C++11, this is not possible at all: return type deduction only applies to lambdas there. It was C++14 which added it for functions too.

Comment: Thanks Angew, well I suppose I have to use another template parameter aswell...

Comment: @MartinZink - You don't

Comment: OP: What @Angew meant is that return type deduction is a C++14 feature so this won't ever compile using a strict C++11 standard compiler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you forget `return` in `GetData()`, `auto` <s>can't work</s> is unuseful to return the same type returned by the `getData()` of the template type (thanks Jarod42!).

Anyway... given a couple of struct as follows

```
struct A
 { int getData () const { return 1; } };

struct B
 { std::string getData () const { return "abc"; } };
```

in C++14 `GetData()` can be written simply as

```
template <class CC>
auto GetData ()
 { return CC{}.getData(); }
```

but this doesn't work in C++11; in C++11 you can write

```
template <class CC>
auto GetData () -> decltype( CC{}.getData() )
 { return CC{}.getData(); }
```

Before C++11 there isn't (this use of) `auto`.

**--- EDIT ---**

As pointed by StoryTeller, the use of `decltype( CC{}.getData() )` assumes that the type `CC` is default constructible.

In the toy example I've written, this isn't a problem because I've used `CC{}` in the body of the function.

In simple cases, you can mirror in the `decltype()` expression what do return in the body of the function; by example, if you pass an object of type `CC`, you can write

```
template <class CC>
auto GetData (CC const & cc) -> decltype( cc.getData() )
 { return cc.getData(); }
```

But isn't ever so simple: there are cases when you know that the value returned is a given expression but the function is to complicated to mirror it in the `decltype()` expression.

So, to avoid the contructible/not constructible problem, it's better use (as suggested by StoryTeller; thanks) `std::declval`; as follows, by example

```
template <class CC>
auto GetData () -> decltype( std::declval<CC>().getData() )
 { /* something complicated ... */ return something.getData(); }
```

Comment: without return, `auto` should be `void`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - you're right; modified my answer to correct this point; thanks.

Comment: Better use `std::declval` in general. Why must a class be default constructible?

Comment: @StoryTeller - uhmmm... in the `decltype()` yes; but you can use `std::declval` in the body of the function?

Comment: @max66 - In your example you construct the object in place, so you have a requirement. The OP's code doesn't need to construct anything with a default constructor, so they should be advised to use `declval`. (Though the OP can also use their own `GetContainer` function directly).

Comment: @StoryTeller - not sure to understand... the bad part is that I'm better in C++ than in english so... modified my answer according what I've understand.